# Issue Parsing a site with lxml and xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I think I am messing up my xpath.  What I am trying to do is get the information of each row on the table in this page.

This is what I have so far but its not outputting what I'm looking for.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

r = requests.get('http://mtgoclanteam.com/Cards?edition=DTK')
doc = etree.HTML(r.text)
#get list of cards
cards = [card for card in doc.xpath('id("cardtable")/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[3]')]
for card in cards:
    print card
```

Comment: And where is your debugging?  If you start with just `id("cardtable")`, does that match an element?  If yes, how about the next segment of your xpath expression? Etc...

Comment: Also! A brief look at that site suggests that the table is filled in *after* the page loads via javascript, so that when you request the page using `requests.get` you are getting an empty table.  Inspect the value of `r.text` after making the request to verify that you are retrieving what you think you are retrieving.

Comment: @larsks yeah you are right the element is only printing one when using `//*[@id="cardtable"]` Now I'm trying to find a way to get this json output

Comment: @har07: `id("cardtable")` is a perfectly valid xpath expression.  You can read about xpath syntax [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id).

Comment: @larsks thanks, I missed that function completely. I think I personally have never seen it used anywhere until this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary problem here is that the actual document served from the server contains an empty table:

```
<table id="cardtable" class="cardlist"/>
```

The data is filled in after the page loads by the embedded javascript that follows the empty table element:

```
<script>
    $('#cardtable').dataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 100, -1], [25, 100, "All"]],


        "bDeferRender": true,
        "aaSorting": [],


        "bPaginate": false,
        "aaData": [
          ...DATA IS HERE...
        ],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Card name", "sWidth": "260" },

                    { "sTitle": "Rarity", "sWidth": "40" },

            { "sTitle": "Buy", "sWidth": "80" },
            { "sTitle": "Sell", "sWidth": "80" },
            { "sTitle": "Bots with stock" }]

    })
</script>
```

The data itself is contained the `aaData` element of the dictionary
that is passed to the `dataTable()` method.  Extracting this in Python
is going to be tricky (this isn't just a JSON document).  Possibly a
suitable regular expression applied to the script text would get you
what you want (or just iterate over the lines of the script and take the one after the `aaData` key).

For example:

```
import pprint
import json
import requests
from lxml import etree

r = requests.get('http://mtgoclanteam.com/Cards?edition=DTK')
doc = etree.HTML(r.text)

script = doc.xpath('id("templatemo_content")/script')[0].text
found = False
result = None
for line in script.splitlines():
    if found:
        if '[' in line:
            result=line
            break
    if 'aaData' in line:
        found = True

if result:
    result =json.loads('[' + result + ']')
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

This is ugly and fragile (it would break if the format of the script
changed), but it works for the current input.

Comment: thank you so much!! I honestly was battling with this for hours.